# How do I open a list of links in new tabs fast?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, links, browser-tabs

I need to review about 1000 pages I have stored in an Excel file.

Is there a browser plugin or online app which would open say 10 URLs I paste in a box in new tabs? Or how could I do this the most efficient way?

Available browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, Safari

Comment: While the other question originally was asked for Ubuntu, you'll find answers both specific to Windows as well as OS and browser-agnostic versions there.

Comment: thx, just what i was looking for but couldnt find it!